# Regular expression find and replace one char to another only in searched phrase

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I want to find text beetwen some tags and replace in this find

one char to another one

example before:

```
432-543-432432value="4aa32-5aa43-432432"
432-543-432432value="432-532-4324-44"
432-543-432432value="2064-43-4-0"
432-543-432432value="643-42-423-52"
432-543-432432value="6-435-4-35-3453"
432-543-432432value="4-32-43-634-53"
```

after:

```
432-543-432432value="4aa32zz5aa43zz432432"
432-543-432432value="432zz532zz4324zz44"
432-543-432432value="2064zz43zz4zz0"
432-543-432432value="643zz42zz423zz52"
432-543-432432value="6zz435zz4zz35zz3453"
432-543-432432value="4zz32zz43zz634zz53"
```

so i want to replace only "-" to "zz" only after value=" and next "

is there any way to do this in notepad++ or other text editor

edge situations:

```
432-543-432432value="---5aa43--432432"
432-543-432432value="---5aa,,43--4324,,32"
432-543-432432value="abc"
432-543-432432value="--abc"
432-543-432432value="--abc--"
432-543-432432value="--"
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this. Have you tried to solve this on your own? Are there any edge cases we should know about?

Comment: @SebastianProske i tried something like that find : (.*").*(") replace: $1zz$2 link : https://regex101.com/r/WdpzoF/1 but couldnt replace only the part of search:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with 2 ways here:

Match every `-` that is not followed by more than 1 `"`. Works fine for all you cases, could be problematic if there can be sequences with `"` in your desired part (something like `value="he-re\"thiswontwork"`)

```
`-(?!(?:[^\n"]*"){2})`
```

using a negative lookahead.

The other approach is to navigate into your desired part of the string and do a series of replacements in there using continuous matching with `\G`

```
(?:value="|\G(?!^))[^-\n]*\K-
```

This matches either `value="` or the position where the last match took place, then a series of characters that are neither `-` nor linebreak. It then resets the match and matches `-`

In both cases your replacement is `zz` or whatever you want to use.